# Making z-order work between fixed and staticaly positioned divs

Tags: html, css

Consider: http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/48/

I want the 'left' div to fall behind the 'ft' div. z-order doesn't work. Note, position of the 'left' div is fixed, but the position of the 'ft' div is not. How do I make 'left' fall behind 'ft'?

Thanks!

Comment: Try position `relative` instead of `static`.  At the moment, there's nothing to scroll in the fiddle, anyway, so I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: scroll is not the issue. i want the ft div to fall above the left div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `position:relative` to your `ft div` instead of `position:static` because `z-index` is only work on **Position** `relative` , `absolute` & `fixed`.